# Fixing RenderFlex Overflow Error in Flutter ToDo App

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, overflow, flutter-renderflex-error

I'm developing a ToDo app using Flutter and encountered a `RenderFlex overflowed` error that I'm struggling to resolve. The debug console provided the following output, indicating that the contents of a `RenderFlex` widget are too big to fit within the available space:

> The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
> The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
> black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
> Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
> RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
> This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
> seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
> ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
> like a ListView.
> The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#33d4b relayoutBoundary=up2 OVERFLOWING:
> needs compositing
> creator: Column ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← SafeArea ← Stack ← LayoutBuilder ← SizedBox ← Center ←
> KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#bf933] ← _BodyBuilder ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← ⋯
> parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=500.0, 0.0<=h<=237.0)
> size: Size(500.0, 237.0)
> direction: vertical

I've isolated the issue to my `ToDoPage` widget, where a `Column` widget containing several child widgets, including text and images, seems to be the source of the problem. Below is the relevant portion of my code:

```dart
class ToDoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ToDoPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ToDoPage> createState() => _ToDoPageState();
}

class _ToDoPageState extends State<ToDoPage> {
  bool isActive = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/mountain.jpg",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 8, 23, 8),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                child: Text(
                                  'My success list',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 30.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 8, 23, 8),
                            child: Tooltip(
                              message: 'List options menu',
                              child: Semantics(
                                label: 'My success list options menu',
                                enabled: true,
                                readOnly: true,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.more_vert_outlined,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    size: 25,
                                    semanticLabel:
                                        'Pomodoro timer list options menu',
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              Text('list options menu')),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 8, 23, 8),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            'Thusrday, December 29, 2022',
                            style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 8, 23, 8),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Glassmorphism(
                            blur: 5,
                            opacity: 0.2,
                            radius: 15,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 100,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        'task 1',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 24.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      SmileFaceCheckbox(
                                          isActive: isActive,
                                          onPress: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              isActive = !isActive;
                                            });
                                          }),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Explain note',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                                        fontSize: 16.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      //hiint
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                                  child: Glassmorphism(
                                    blur: 20,
                                    opacity: 0.1,
                                    radius: 15.0,
                                    child: TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        // handle push to HomeScreen
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          vertical: 10.0,
                                          horizontal: 15.0,
                                        ),
                                        child: Text(
                                          '+ Add successful task',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 20.0,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In an attempt to fix the issue, I've tried wrapping the problematic `Column` widget in a `SingleChildScrollView` and using `Expanded` widgets around my text widgets, but the overflow error persists.

Here's a snippet of the attempted fix:

```
SafeArea(
  child: Expanded(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
         
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

And for the text widgets:

```
child: Flexible(
  child: Text(
    'My success list',
    style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 30.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    ),
  ),
)
```

I've also included custom widgets `Glassmorphism` and `SmileFaceCheckbox` in my UI. Could these be affecting layout calculations?

Update:

Glassmorphism.dart

```
  import 'dart:ui';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class Glassmorphism extends StatelessWidget {
      final double blur;
      final double opacity;
      final double radius;
      final Widget child;
    
      const Glassmorphism({
        Key? key,
        required this.blur,
        required this.opacity,
        required this.radius,
        required this.child,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: blur, sigmaY: blur),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(opacity),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(radius)),
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 1.5,
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                ),
              ),
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Smileyface.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SmileFaceCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
  final double height;
  final bool isActive;
  final VoidCallback onPress;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color deactiveColor;

  const SmileFaceCheckbox({
    Key? key,
    this.height = 24.0,
    required this.isActive,
    required this.onPress,
  })  : activeColor = const Color.fromARGB(255, 116, 217, 48),
        deactiveColor = const Color(0xffD94530),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SmileFaceCheckbox> createState() => _SmileFaceCheckboxState();
}

class _SmileFaceCheckboxState extends State<SmileFaceCheckbox>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _animationValue;

  void setupAnimation() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );

    _animationValue = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: const Interval(0.0, 1.0),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    setupAnimation();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = widget.height;
    final width = height * 2;
    final largeRadius = (height * 0.9) / 2;
    final smallRadius = (height * 0.2) / 2;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: widget.onPress,
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animationController,
        builder: (context, _) {
          if (widget.isActive) {
            _animationController.forward();
          } else {
            _animationController.reverse();
          }
          return Container(
            height: height,
            width: width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0),
              color:
                  widget.isActive ? widget.activeColor : widget.deactiveColor,
             
            ),
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(
                      -largeRadius + largeRadius * 2 * _animationValue.value,
                      0), // add animation move from -largeRadius to largeRadius
                  child: Container(
                    width: largeRadius * 2,
                    height: largeRadius * 2,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset(0, -smallRadius),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: smallRadius * 2,
                                height: smallRadius * 2,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: widget.isActive
                                      ? widget.activeColor
                                      : widget.deactiveColor,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: smallRadius * 2,
                                height: smallRadius * 2,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: widget.isActive
                                      ? widget.activeColor
                                      : widget.deactiveColor,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset(0, smallRadius * 2),
                          child: Container(
                            width: smallRadius * 4,
                            height:
                                widget.isActive ? smallRadius * 2 : smallRadius,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: widget.isActive
                                  ? widget.activeColor
                                  : widget.deactiveColor,
                              borderRadius: !widget.isActive
                                  ? BorderRadius.circular(22.0)
                                  : const BorderRadius.only(
                                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                                    ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I resolve the `RenderFlex overflowed` error in my Flutter app, ensuring all content fits within the available space without overflow?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you include more about `Glassmorphism`

Comment: `Glassmorphism` defination please

Comment: Can you also add `SmileFaceCheckbox` widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, I added the smiley face widget

Comment: Update all the required code , so that we can reproduce that in our machine and let you know the corrections

Comment: I test your snippet but cant reproduce the error

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, try to play with the responsiveness of the website from bottom to top, it should appear the error

Comment: ok you need to make it scrollable

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, I wrapped the  `Column` to a `SingleChildScrollView` widget but don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `bottomNavigationBar` for adding that item. and use Column[HeaderWidget,Expanded(ListViwe)] or just body:ListView on Scaffold body .

You can play with decoration, It depends on your ux how you like to handle scroll event, you may like SliverAppBar on CustomScrolView

```dart
class _ToDoPageState extends State<ToDoPage> {
  bool isActive = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 42, 36, 36),
        // floatingActionButton: newTaskButton(),
        bottomNavigationBar: newTaskButton(),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                //   child: Image.asset(
                //     "assets/mountain.jpg",
                //     fit: BoxFit.cover,
                //   ),
              ),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 8, 23, 8),
                            child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                              child: Text(
                                'My success list',
                                style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 30.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 8, 23, 8),
                          child: Tooltip(
                            message: 'List options menu',
                            child: Semantics(
                              label: 'My success list options menu',
                              enabled: true,
                              readOnly: true,
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.more_vert_outlined,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 25,
                                  semanticLabel:
                                      'Pomodoro timer list options menu',
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 8, 23, 8),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          'Thusrday, December 29, 2022',
                          style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23, 8, 23, 8),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Glassmorphism(
                          blur: 5,
                          opacity: 0.2,
                          radius: 15,
                          child: Container(
                            height: 100,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'task 1',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 24.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SmileFaceCheckbox(
                                        isActive: isActive,
                                        onPress: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            isActive = !isActive;
                                          });
                                        }),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Explain note',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    //hiint

                    // SizedBox(
                    //   height: constraints.maxHeight * .4, // your height
                    // ),
                    // Align(
                    //   alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                    //   child: newTaskButton(),
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column newTaskButton() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 15.0),
          child: Glassmorphism(
            blur: 20,
            opacity: 0.1,
            radius: 15.0,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // handle push to HomeScreen
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 10.0,
                  horizontal: 15.0,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  '+ Add successful task',
                  style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```